# Chart.js - Scale of secondary y-axis?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chart.js, ruby-on-rails-6, chartkick

I am using Chartkick + Chart.js to plot 2 series of different scale ($/% or 0./$ etc.).
Using this code it works but the secondary y-asix scale is 0 to 1. 
I would scale (min/max) to be automatically recognized based on data.

[image: by]

```
<%=line_chart url_for(action: :chart, metric_left: params[:metric_left], metric_right: params[:metric_right], days: 30, format: :json), 
                    points: false, precision: 2,  messages: {empty: "No data"}, library: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [
                {
                    id: params[:metric_left],
                    type: 'linear',
                    position: 'left',
                    gridLines: {display: false},

                }, 
                {
                    id: params[:metric_right],
                    type: 'linear',
                    position: 'right',
                    gridLines: {display: false},

                }
            ]
        }
    }%>
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved adding the yAxisID in the returned JSON

```
[{
   "dataset": {
     "yAxisID": "impressions" <-------
   },
   "name": "impressions",
   "data": {
     "2020-03-30": 30846,
     "2020-03-31": 34019,
    "2020-04-01": 40007,
    "2020-04-02": 43751,
```

...